# How to access monitoring services (prometheus, kibana etc.) deployed in Kubernetes production

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kibana, prometheus, monitoring

I have web services running in the GKE Kubernetes Engine. I also have monitoring services running in the cloud that are monitoring these services. Everything is working fine....except that I don't know how to access the Prometheus, and Kibana dashboards. I know I can use **port-forward** to temporarily forward a local port and access that way but that cannot scale with more and more engineers using the system. I was thinking of a way to provide access to these dashboards to engineers but not sure what would be the best way.

1. Should I create a load balancer for each of these?
2. What about security? I only want a few engineers to have access to these systems.

There are other considerations as well, would love to get your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I create a load balancer for each of these?

No, you can create but not a good idea.

> What about security? I only want a few engineers to have access to
> these systems.

You can create an account in Kibana and manage access or else you can use the **IAP** `(Identity-Aware Proxy)` to restrict access. [Ref doc](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/user-auth-with-iap#0)

You have multiple options. You can use the LoadBalancer as you used but not a good idea though.

A good way to expose different applications is using the **ingress**. So i you are running the **Prometheus**, **Jaeger**, and **Kibana** in your **GKE**.

You can create the different hosts with **domain prom.example.com**, **tracing.example.com**, **kibana.example.com** so there will be **single ingress controller** service with type **LoadBalancer** and you can map **IP** to **DNS**.

[Ref doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#creating_an_ingress_resource)